# How to define compiler symbol in Lazarus IDE?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I need to define compiler symbol (say `MYSYMBOL`) in Lazarus project options (Lazarus 2.0.2) and cannot find how to do it.

That is, I need an equivalent of

```
{$DEFINE MYSYMBOL}
```

defined in project options which I guess will be transformed into compiler option `-dMYSYMBOL`.

How to do it?

Comment: See https://wiki.freepascal.org/IDE_Window:_Compiler_Options#Custom_Options

Comment: @LURD Please enter the comment as answer.

Comment: Note that there is also -dxxx:=yyy which defines a macro xxx as yyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the project settings for compiler options under [Custom Options](https://wiki.freepascal.org/IDE_Window:_Compiler_Options#Custom_Options)